# Extracting of the text data using bash utilities

Tags: bash, text, multiple-columns

I have non-trivial task to extract some relevant data from the big CSV logs which looks like

```
Frame #,Residue,Internal,van der Waals,Electrostatic,Polar Solvation,Non-Polar Solv.,TOTAL
1,1,119.745,0.356,-132.009,-95.618,1.7886312,-105.7373688
1,2,106.093,-3.835,-182.473,40.582,0.7132608,-38.9197392
1,3,21.228,-1.744,-38.026,-7.707,1.1189664,-25.1300336
1,4,-5.717,-4.721,-30.38,-4.839,0.406512,-45.250488
1,5,70.846,-4.127,-53.317,-2.534,0.7808472,11.6488472
...
2,1,119.745,0.356,-132.009,-95.618,1.7886312,-105.7373688
2,2,106.093,-3.835,-182.473,40.582,0.7132608,-38.9197392
2,3,21.228,-1.744,-38.026,-7.707,1.1189664,-25.1300336
2,4,-5.717,-4.721,-30.38,-4.839,0.406512,-45.250488
2,5,70.846,-4.127,-53.317,-2.534,0.7808472,11.6488472
...
n,1,119.745,0.356,-132.009,-95.618,1.7886312,-105.7373688
n,2,106.093,-3.835,-182.473,40.582,0.7132608,-38.9197392
n,3,21.228,-1.744,-38.026,-7.707,1.1189664,-25.1300336
n,4,-5.717,-4.721,-30.38,-4.839,0.406512,-45.250488
n,5,70.846,-4.127,-53.317,-2.534,0.7808472,11.6488472
```

here I'd like to chose specified one value from 2nd column (#residue) and write evolution(function of #snapshot number column) of its last column (#total energy) according to the 1st column (#frame number). In other words I need to 1) sort all of the data in accordance with the 2nd column first): i.e to select each string where the number in second column equal to specified value (i.e n=27)

```
#Frame, #Residue

1,27, ... , # last column value which is interested for me!
2,27, ... , # last column value which is interested for me!
3,27, ... , # last column value which is interested for me!
3,27, ... , # last column value which is interested for me!
```

and than extract corresponding values of its last column so the resululting log will have onlu 3 columns:

```
#Frame, #Residue, # Total energy

1,27, # last column value which is interested for me!
2,27, # last column value which is interested for me!
3,27, # last column value which is interested for me!
3,27, # last column value which is interested for me!
```

Will be thankful for any realization using awk and sed!

Thanks!

Gleb

Answer (score 2):

To extract the lines with 27 in the second column, you can use `grep`:

```
  grep '^[^,]\+,27,' input.csv
        | |   |
beginning |   |
    not comma |
              repeated
```

To only output the 1st, 2nd and 8th column, use `cut`:

```
grep '^[^,]\+,27' input.csv | cut -d, -f1,2,8
                                   |   |
                             delimiter |
                                      fields
```

To sort the files by the second column, you can use `sort`:

```
sort -t, -nk2,2 input.csv
      |   | |
delimiter | |
    numeric |
    sort    by only the second field
```

Comment: You can add a comma after "27", otherwise it can match biggest number like 270, 271, 271337...:
`grep '^[^,]\+,27,' input.csv | cut -d, -f1,2,8`

Comment: `\+` is undefined in POSIX basic regular expressions, so you're relying on a grep that happens to treat `\+` to mean "1 or more". That said, it should really be `*` instead.

Comment: thx! one question: what to add to the script to stop such extraction of the lines after the i-th extraction from the initial data.csv?  E,g to extract only  n lines using such command.

Comment: @user3470313: You can pipe the output to `head`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an awk solution:

```
awk -v n=27 'BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," } $2 == n { print $1, $2, $NF }' input.csv
```

- `-v n=27` - starts by assigning an awk variable `n` the value `27`
- `BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," }` - The BEGIN section is run before awk starts parsing any data. Here we set FS (field separator) and OFS (output field separator) both to ",", so that both the input lines and output lines will be split/separated by commas.
- `$2 == n { print $1, $2, $NF }` - For any record (line) where the second field ($2) equals n, output the first, second and last fields.

To stop after *m* matches:

```
awk -v n=27 -v m=3 'BEGIN { OFS = FS = "," } $2 == n { print $1, $2, $NF; if (++count == m) exit}' input.csv
```

Comment: thx! the question again: what to add to the script to stop such extraction of the lines after the i-th extraction from the initial data.csv? E,g to extract only n lines using such command.